# Why does my iOS device beep at noon every day?

Tags: ios, ipod-touch

I have an iPod touch (4th gen). A few weeks ago, it started making an alert sound (tritone) every day at exactly 12 noon. There is no on-screen alert, nothing in the Notification Center pull-down. Just a sound. Every day.

I have NO apps in my Notifications (Settings). I have NO alarms set. NO reoccurring calendar items.

Anyone have a clue why my device is doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by you have no "*apps in my Notifications (Settings)*"? Are you referring to the Notification Center, or the list of apps in Settings? If it's the latter, I don't understand how there can be **no** apps in that list since pre-installed iOS apps will be shown in that list, and they can't be removed…

Comment: I mean in Settings > Notifications, the list under "In Notification Center" says "Empty".

Comment: If you were like me, you followed all these directions and still got mystery beeps. I posted a supplemental question/answer here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116576/why-does-my-ios-device-beep-and-vibrate-even-after-turning-off-sounds-in-every

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the app in the list, there should be a description of which types of notification an app can send. Look through the list for apps that say 'Alerts' or 'Sounds' and disable the 'Alert Tone' or 'Sounds' respectively.

[image]

Comment: Yup. That was it, although I'm sure the I never allowed the offending app to set any notifications. Thanks.

Comment: @KevinT Curious—what was the offending app?