# How can Transit app vibrate my phone even with notification sounds turned off?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, vibrate

I've been tweaking my notification settings for various apps recently, and today I noticed something very peculiar.

I was using the [Transit App](https://transitapp.com/) in **Go** mode as I do on most days. As I approached my destination, I felt my phone vibrate... but I had already turned off Sounds in the notification settings for this app! *(See below)* I'm sure the vibrate was from Transit App because I had exactly one notification in my Notification Centre right after I got the vibration.

Is there any way to suppress vibrations from app notifications, since apparently turning off sounds doesn't do it?

[image]

Additional info about my phone settings:

- Silent switch: Off
- Do Not Disturb: Off
- Vibrate on Ring: On
- Vibrate on Silent: Off
- Ringer volume: 50%
- System Haptics: On

Comment: I did find a [related question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116576/why-does-my-ios-device-beep-and-vibrate-even-after-turning-off-sounds-in-every) but the answers there were only about Calendar app, and I'm sure my question isn't about Calendar app.

Comment: Transit seems to have some kind of special permissions, because I’ve noticed the notifications buzz even with “do not disturb” activated. I’ve been curious about this too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Transit App is in **Go** mode, it can deliver notifications using the Turn-by-turn API which has some special privileges.

- *Vibration* is possible if Notifications are turned on for Transit App, even if all the specific options are turned off. Disabling notifications for the app prevents vibration.
- *Audible* announcement of upcoming stops is permitted even if notifications are entirely disabled for Transit App. But of course audible announcements will only play if enabled in Transit App by toggling the sound icon in Go mode.

These special notifications also seem to bypass Do Not Disturb mode.